# Choosing Pattern for winform application

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Can anyone please guide me in choosing the pattern for the application which iam going to develop in winforms C#?

> Application purpose is to import xml file and export some properties from xml file to Excel sheet and UI will be through winforms.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific patterns for windows forms. You can apply SOLID Principles and Design Patterns which will offer a reliable, flexible and low coupled application development. SOLID Principles are design methodologies, which you can apply when design a class.

Fore more about SOLID Principles visit 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60845/The-S-O-L-I-D-Object-Oriented-Programming-OOP-Prin

Design patterns usage will depends on how you implement the functionality in your project

Fore more about Design Patterns visit
http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx